# Как выполнить javascript на сервере?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть хостинг с доступом к FTP, возможностью выполнять php. Есть JS который когда зайти на сайт выполняет некие запросы к API ВКонтакте. Но когда закрыть страницу, запросы отсылаться перестают, оно и логично.
Как сделать, чтобы запросы отправлялись с сервера когда я захочу? Т. е. чтобы JS выполнялся на сервере в любое время круглосуточно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать API для серверных обращений, [в контакте все написано](https://vk.com/dev/secure).

Для начала работы вам надо получить [access_token](https://vk.com/dev/secure_how_to) через запрос:

> 'https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=' + APP_ID + '&client_secret=' + APP_SECRET + '&grant_type=client_credentials'

Это само собой происходит на сервере.

По токенам от пользователя у вас отправить не получится, т.к. проверяется IP запроса.

В общем [справка контакта в руки](https://vk.com/dev/apiusage), и удачи! :)